# Possible to automatically update plugin without user interaction

Tags: plugins, automatic-updates

I am developing a plugin and I would like my plugin to auto-update. By auto-update I mean, it will somehow know that a new version is available and automatically update without user interaction.

- Does the WordPress API have functions/ability to automatically update/install a new version of a plugin without user interaction?

Answer (score 0):

If you upload it to the Wordpress repository it should be able to auto-update (if you're not blocking this setting as explained on [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates)).